# Insert Random Number Every Other Space in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, random

I'd like to be able to take a variable that is a set of numbers in string form, for example call it `str`, and insert a random number between 1 and 10 every other space in that string. Right now I have this code:

```
str.toString().match(/.{1}/g).join((Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) 
+ 1)).toString())
```

This almost does it, however it will generate one random number and insert that every time instead of generating new random numbers for every other space. For example, if `str = '1234567890'`, I'd like it to turn into something like `18293547596173889302` but instead I get something like `182838485868789808`. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The code that you've shown calculates the `(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) 
+ 1)).toString()` part *once*, and passes the result to the `.join()` method.

I'd consider using the string `.replace()` method instead, because then you can use a function that will be called once per replacement:

```js
var str = '1234567890'

var output = str.replace(/./g, function(m) { 
  return m + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)
})

console.log(output)
```

`/./g` matches every character, one at a time, and the matched character is passed to the callback function so you can use it in the replacement.

Note that the `+` concatenation operator converts the random number to a string automatically, so you don't need to call `.toString()` yourself.

**EDIT:** Note that your original `.join()` code inserted new digits *between* the existing digits, so didn't add anything after the input's last character, but your sample output added a random digit after every existing digit including the last one. My code does the latter. If you don't want to add that last random digit at the end it can be removed by calling `.slice(0, -1)` on the result.

Comment: Thanks so much! Both answers I got work perfectly so I'll just pick one and go with it!

Comment: You're welcome. (By the way, it seems a bit weird to insert the numbers 1-10 between the input's digits, rather than 0-9, because that means the total length of the output is variable depending on how many times 10 is randomly chosen, but if that's what you want that's what you've got.)

Comment: Oh true thanks for that also haha. To fix that should I just remove the + 1?

Comment: Yep, remove the +1. See also my edit relating to the difference between inserting random digits *between* each character in the input and adding random digits *after* each character in the input...

Comment: Yeah. I wanted to have a random digit after every other character, so ending with a random character was the desired result

Answer (score 1):

You could use map like this

```js
var str = '1234567890';
var result = str.toString().split('').map(n => n + (Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) 
+ 1))).join('');
console.log(result);
```